# What did Einstein make of Bohmian Mechanics?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, history-of-philosophy, ontology, philosophy-of-physics

Its well-known that Einstein was uncomfortable about the anti-realist and non-deterministic status of Quantum Mechanics, declaring that

> God does not play dice

However, a realist and deterministic interpretation of Quantum Mechanics was [found](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/qm-bohm/#o) by de Broglie in 1927, and then rediscovered by Bohm in 1952. This is generally called de Broglie-Bohm or just Bohmian Mechanics.

What was Einsteins response to this?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_de_Broglie):

> His 1924 *Recherches sur la théorie des quanta* (Research on the Theory of the Quanta), introduced his theory of electron waves. This included the wave–particle duality theory of matter, based on the work of Max Planck and Albert Einstein on light. The thesis examiners, unsure of the material, passed his thesis to Einstein for evaluation who endorsed his wave–particle duality proposal wholeheartedly; de Broglie was awarded his doctorate.

Based on this, Einstein seems to have approved of de Broglie's work and therefore Bohmian Mechanics.

Comment: sure, this is well-known - at least its something that I was told of when studying Physics at college (quite some time ago). I'm curious to how he reacted to Broglies later work on a realist interpretation. Its not a simple jump from the early days of QM to Bohmian Mechanics.